# Found the NXT device but can not upload a program to NXT

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, nxt

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit). After installing leJOS_NXJ_0.9.1beta-3, I was able to flash the NXT device. However, when I tried to upload a program, it showed a message "Found NXT: NXT 0016530CDF15" and then just stuck there.

I also tried Eclipse with leJOS plugin, and got the same problem. It showed 
Program has been linked successfully
Uploading ...
Found NXT: NXT 0016530CDF15

and it got stucked there.

Can anybody help me with this issue?
Thanks,
Thuy

Comment: Please explain what “it got stucked there” means. You have a motor connected to your Lego NXT, the motor started up and your NXT rolled into a crevice and now it can't roll out?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I mean it showed the message and didn't return  to the console, it was uploading .... and never finished the job so it just kept uploading...

Answer (score 0):

This site might be able to help, it provides the information to install and configure correctly all the software necessary for you to develop Java programs for the NXT, maybe by following this site it will hopefully fix the problem.

This tutorial will show you how to install and configure all the software necessary for you to develop Java programs for the LEGO Mindstorms NXT. Java is much more powerful and flexible than the original NXT-G software that LEGO provides. We will be using the Eclipse editor to write the actual Java code and to download this into the NXT. This combination enables you to conveniently write software and to quickly test it on the NXT. Of course there are many other Java editors, but we consider this combination to be particularly convenient. This tutorial focuses on the Windows XP platform, A Mac OS X tutorial is also available. We have two additional steps for Windows Vista. You will work through the following five steps - See more at: http://www.bartneck.de/2008/03/04/java-lego-nxt-eclipse-tutorial/#sthash.h1ZOZvlX.dpuf